# SQL Server Trigger on Specified Columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

**Hey,**

I am trying to update some columns in my table in `SQL Server 2014` and I wrote some code on the `trigger` and to consequently insert the new values into a new table, using the following code procedure:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Atrin Noori
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UsersOnUPDATE] 
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   After UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --
    DECLARE @user_key int
    SELECT @user_key = i.User_key FROM inserted i;
    --  
    IF UPDATE (User_fullname) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @newfullname nvarchar(MAX);
        DECLARE @oldfullname nvarchar(MAX);
        --
        SELECT @oldfullname = i.User_fullname FROM deleted i;
        SELECT @newfullname = i.User_fullname FROM inserted i;
        --
        INSERT INTO UsersLogs (UL_user_key_r, UL_date, UL_oldname, UL_newname, UL_IsDeleted)
        VALUES (@user_key, GETDATE(), @oldfullname, @newfullname, 0)
    END
    --
    ELSE IF UPDATE (User_password) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @newpassword nvarchar(10);
        DECLARE @oldpassword nvarchar(10);      
        -- 
        SELECT @oldpassword = i.User_password FROM deleted i;
        SELECT @newpassword = i.User_password FROM inserted i;
        --
        INSERT INTO UsersLogs (UL_user_key_r,UL_date,UL_oldpass,UL_newpass,UL_IsDeleted)
        VALUES (@user_key, GETDATE(), @oldpassword, @newpassword, 0)
    END 
    --
    ELSE IF UPDATE (User_username) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @newusername nvarchar(10);
        DECLARE @oldusername nvarchar(10);
        --
        SELECT @oldusername = i.User_username FROM deleted i;
        SELECT @newusername = i.User_username FROM inserted i;
        --
        INSERT INTO UsersLogs (UL_user_key_r, UL_date, UL_oldusername, UL_newusername, UL_IsDeleted)
        VALUES (@user_key, GETDATE(), @oldusername, @newusername, 0)
    END
    --
    ELSE IF UPDATE (User_position_id_r) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @newposid tinyint;
        DECLARE @oldposid tinyint;
        --
        SELECT @oldposid = i.User_position_id_r FROM deleted i;
        SELECT @newposid = i.User_position_id_r FROM inserted i;
        --
        INSERT INTO UsersLogs (UL_user_key_r, UL_date, UL_oldPosid, UL_newPosid, UL_IsDeleted)
        VALUES (@user_key, GETDATE(), @oldposid, @newposid, 0)
    END
END
```

This trigger works fine when I manually change the values in each column and inserts into a new table called `UsersLogs`.
However it does not work fine when I use the c# application I am developing to update the values...

***CONSIDER:***

> I am trying to change the password of a user through my application
> and using a `Stored Procedure`.

The `Stored Procedure` works fine and updates the values, **BUT** the trigger of `UserOnUpdate` inserts the `old` and `new` value of `User_Fullnme` (not oldpassword and newpassword)  into the new table `(UsersLgos)` and set others to null (which is OK to be null).

I mean only this part of code will run:

```sql
IF UPDATE (User_fullname) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @newfullname nvarchar(MAX);
        DECLARE @oldfullname nvarchar(MAX);
        --
        SELECT @oldfullname = i.User_fullname FROM deleted i;
        SELECT @newfullname = i.User_fullname FROM inserted i;
        --
        INSERT INTO UsersLogs (UL_user_key_r, UL_date, UL_oldname, UL_newname, UL_IsDeleted)
        VALUES (@user_key, GETDATE(), @oldfullname, @newfullname, 0)
    END
```

And by the things I just said... I change the password and SET a condition to check for the updated column.

But the question is why the trigger cannot realize which column was updated through the application ?

**NOTE:**

> I say it again: **IT WORKS FINE WITH THE MANUAL CHANGES AND UPDATES**

Comment: In general `deleted` and `inserted` contain a **set** of records, not just a single one. So your `SELECT`s into a scalar variable from them don't make sense in general. You first need to fix that fundamental flaw before anything else.

Comment: but it works fine in manual update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `UPDATE()` function only tells you if a column was *present* in the `UPDATE` statement**, not if the value actually changed. Furthermore, te `inserted` and `deleted` tables **may contain multiple rows, or none**.

So, your trigger should really look like this:

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UsersOnUPDATE] 
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   After UPDATE
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT (UPDATE(User_fullname) OR UPDATE(User_password) OR UPDATE(User_username) OR UPDATE(User_position_id_r))
    RETURN;  -- this only tells you if the column was present

INSERT INTO UsersLogs
    (UL_user_key_r, UL_date, UL_IsDeleted,
    UL_oldname, UL_newname,
    UL_oldpass, UL_newpass,
    UL_oldusername, UL_newusername,
    UL_oldPosid, UL_newPosid)
SELECT
    i.user_key, GETDATE(), 0,
    d.fullname, i.fullname,
    d.User_password, i.User_password,
    d.User_username, i.User_username,
    d.User_position_id_r, i.User_position_id_r
FROM inserted i
JOIN deleted d ON i.user_key = d.user_key
WHERE EXISTS (    -- this checks for any differences
    SELECT i.fullname, i.User_password, i.User_username, i.User_position_id_r
    EXCEPT        -- this will deal with nulls correctly
    SELECT d.fullname, d.User_password, d.User_username, d.User_position_id_r
);
```

In case of only some columns being updated, this does leave you with the other columns having the same before and after values. But some `CASE` expressions should sort that out.

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UsersOnUPDATE] 
   ON  [dbo].[Users]
   After UPDATE
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT (UPDATE(User_fullname) OR UPDATE(User_password) OR UPDATE(User_username) OR UPDATE(User_position_id_r))
    RETURN;  -- this only tells you if the column was present

INSERT INTO UsersLogs
    (UL_user_key_r, UL_date, UL_IsDeleted,
    UL_oldname, UL_newname,
    UL_oldpass, UL_newpass,
    UL_oldusername, UL_newusername,
    UL_oldPosid, UL_newPosid)
SELECT
    i.user_key, GETDATE(), 0,
    CASE WHEN d.fullname <> i.fullname THEN d.fullname END, CASE WHEN d.fullname <> i.fullname THEN i.fullname END
    CASE WHEN d.User_password <> i.User_password THEN d.User_password END, CASE WHEN d.User_password <> i.User_password THEN i.User_password END,
    CASE WHEN d.User_username <> i.User_username THEN d.User_username END, CASE WHEN d.User_username <> i.User_username THEN i.User_username END,
    CASE WHEN d.User_position_id_r <> i.User_position_id_r THEN d.User_position_id_r END, CASE WHEN d.User_position_id_r <> i.User_position_id_r THEN i.User_position_id_r END
FROM inserted i
JOIN deleted d ON i.user_key = d.user_key
WHERE EXISTS (    -- this checks for any differences
    SELECT i.fullname, i.User_password, i.User_username, i.User_position_id_r
    EXCEPT        -- this will deal with nulls correctly
    SELECT d.fullname, d.User_password, d.User_username, d.User_position_id_r
);
```

If you want separate rows for every value changed, you could unpivot with a `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: There is a problem with this and that is that it fills all the columns and doesnt set the unchanged ones to null

Comment: OK given you the `CASE` solutions for that

Comment: :) tnQ  And Yes it works just fine 
so the thing is ```UPDATE()``` watches for present columns... good

Answer (score 1):

`update()` trigger function , returns true if the column is updated even if with the same value.
so seems like when you update password, you are updating User_fullname column and other columns probably (with the same value as before of course) . so UPDATE (User_fullname) returns true .

But, also the way you have've written your code , the trigger works for the situation only one column is updated and in that order in your code , for example if `UPDATE (User_fullname)`  is true , your code doesn't check other conditions , because of `ELSE IF`. you might wanna remove `else` and check for each column , or totally change your strategy to log data inside trigger.

then based on your comment , get rid of all if else and have one single insert statement like so for all columns:

```
INSERT INTO UsersLogs (UL_user_key_r,UL_date,UL_oldpass,UL_newpass,<all columns>)
select (@user_key, GETDATE(), case when deleted.password <> new.password then deleted.password else null end , case when deleted.password <> new.password then inserted.password else null end , ....)
from inserted i
join deleted d on i.userkey = d.userkey
```

Comment: Yeap I got suspicious and I removed the "```ELSE```" part, and guess what happened?
it inserted 8 rows to the log table which was fine in a matter that it could log all the changes but... I want to keep my database in the most lessen type possible... so others will be set to null but I don't want 8 rows my table

Comment: I think the bug is with the stored procedure , because when I replace a value with its own value it doesn't see it as an update or change but when the stored procedure updates a column with its own value it consider it as an update.... So I change some parts of the code..
I deleted the ```else``` part and I set another condition to check whether the ```old value``` is equal to the ```new value``` and if it was not the insert the log it reduces the 8 rows to 3 or even less or others depending on altered columns but if I find a way to insert all the changes into one row that would be great :)

Comment: Ok i Just saw your update version lemme check ofc I think it works fine

Comment: @Charlieface yeah but users in my database has one row each and that's fine for me

Comment: @AtrinNoori I updated my answer anyway to reflect that anyways,